# AFNetworking 2.0 and Response Serialization Options

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

As soon as I trigger a request to a JSON resource I get the following:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x1d87a2c0 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

The problem is that where should I set the allow fragments in AFNetworking 2.0?

UPDATE:

My class is a sub class of AFHTTPSessionManager. I already have created a JSONResponseSerializer and it also does not work.

JSON being returned is as follows:

```
   [{"StoryId":1,"Title":"The big red dog","Abstract":"There was a big red dog and the dog was very big","IsFeatured":true}]

-(instancetype) initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSURL *base = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URL to the web service that returns the json"];
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:base];

    AFJSONResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];

    [self setResponseSerializer:responseSerializer];

    return self;
}
```

The error returned is the following:

```
[0] (null)  @"NSDebugDescription" : @"Invalid value around character 0."
```

**RESPONSE FROM WEB SERVER:**

```
[{"StoryId":1,"Title":"The big red dog","Abstract":"There was a big red dog and the dog was very big","IsFeatured":true}]
```

**RESPONSE STATUS FROM WEB SERVER:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
Connection: close
Date: Mon, 28 Oct 2013 20:02:21 GMT
Content-Length: 121
Cache-Control: private
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319

[{"StoryId":1,"Title":"The big red dog","Abstract":"There was a big red dog and the dog was very big","IsFeatured":true}]
```

Comment: That's a problem with the web server's response, **not** with AFNetworking.

Comment: The response is valid! I just validated the JSON and it is valid JSON being returned.

Comment: I didn't say it's *invalid*. I said that the *problem is caused by it*. JSON data tend to be contained within an array or object. @Wain is right, you have to tell AFNetworking which options should `NSJSONSerialization` use to read the JSON data.

Comment: I already did that see my updated question!

Comment: Ah, I saw your edit and I take back my words.

Answer (score 7):

You need to create your own instance of `AFJSONResponseSerializer` using `serializerWithReadingOptions:` and configure your system to use it (in place of the default JSON response serialiser).

Comment: Please see my updated question! I added the AFJSONResponseSerializer but still no use!

Comment: Your JSON doesn't look like it has fragments. Are you sure your custom class is being used?

Comment: ... and are you sure the response isn't corrupted or enclosed within something else?

Comment: Please see the question for heading "RESPONSE FROM WEB SERVER". That is the actual response I get.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem before. And after few hours searching and reading, I found something:

> self.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
>           self.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8", nil];

try it and good luck!